Why does the word "ahínco" carry an accent mark if it is llana?
The word "ahínco" is llana. It has three syllables: a-hín-co. As the stress falls on the penultimate syllable the word is llana and the rules regarding when to use a tilde say that all llana words that DO NOT end in -n, -s or a vowel should carry a tilde.
Thus, why does "ahínco" carry a tilde? Is it just an exception to the rule or is there something else going on here?

Compare árbol.

Hay una regla en si misma que indica que debe tildarse, independientemente de las otras reglas (vamos, puedes llamarle una excepción si quieres).
La respuesta está en el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, en el artículo tilde, en la sección 2.3.2. Acentuación gráfica de las palabras con hiato:
Cito:

a) Las palabras con hiato formado por una vocal cerrada tónica y una vocal abierta átona, o por una vocal abierta átona y una cerrada tónica, siempre llevan tilde sobre la vocal cerrada, con independencia de lo que establecen las reglas generales de acentuación: armonía, grúa, insinúe, dúo, río, hematíe, laúd, caída, raíz, feúcho, cafeína, egoísmo, oír.

El resaltado es mío.
Viendo el caso específico, ahínco tiene hiato1 (que no se rompe con la h2) de una vocal abierta átona (a) y una vocal cerrada tónica (i), por lo cual, según esta regla, siempre se tilda en la vocal tónica.

1 hiato:

3. Secuencia de dos vocales que se pronuncian en sílabas distintas.

2 hiato:

3. La h intercalada no influye en la consideración como diptongo o como hiato de una secuencia vocálica. Así, hay grupos de vocales con h intermedia que forman diptongo: ahijado, desahucio, prohibir; y otros que forman hiato: ahínco, turbohélice, prohíbe.


Entonces, si he entendido bien, la palabra hiato ella misma es un ejemplo de palabras con hiato?  Imagino que se pronuncia como hi-ato con la i y la a separadas, cierto?

No, "hiato" contiene diptongo. Se pronuncia: ia-to


ahincar(se)

'Hincar(se) o fijar(se)' y 'esforzarse o perseverar con ahínco'. Se acentúa como aislar (→ apéndice 1, aislar). La hache intercalada no exime de la obligación de tildar la -i- para marcar el hiato en las formas en que esta vocal es tónica (→ tilde2, 2.3.2.a): ahínco, ahíncas, ahínca, ahíncan, ahínque, ahínques, ahínquen.


RAE

Just to add to the other answers, it might be important to clarify what "hiato" means. "Hiato" is the opposite of "diphthong", that is, "hiato" exists when, instead of both vowels remaining within the same syllable, they each form part of a different syllable.
If the word "ahínco" were not stressed, instead of being correctly pronounced /a-'in-ko/, it would be incorrectly pronounced /'ain-ko/.
Let's see how the stress in a hiato works to differentiate the stressed word from an unstressed one (where I say "stress", I mean "tilde", that is, a written stress).
Here we can find some examples:

Río /'ri-o/ (hiato): river
Rio* /ri'o/ (diptongo): (he/she) laughed

(*) Before the last amendment to Spanish spelling rules, this word was written with a stress on "o": rió. However, since it is a one-syllable word, the general rule now prescribes it goes unstressed.

Does this mean that the infinitive ahincar is pronounced as two syllables, exactly as if it were spelled aincar?

All infinitives are stressed on the last syllable. In the case of "ahincar" (a verb I have never used or heard anyone use in my whole life), there might be a secondary stress on the "a" of "ai" (the "h" is irrelevant as to the existence of hiato or diptongo) for the diphthong to be pronounced in one syllable: ain-'kar

In these two words, there is a diphthong irrespective of the "h": aullar /au-'∫ar/ (to howl) / ahuyentar /au-∫en-'tar/ (to scare away)

Good to know, thank you!

Oh, I just realized that jachguate's answer already covered that (in the quotation in the second footnote). My bad!
